# How to design custom alert dialog in android

Tags: android, filter, model, android-arrayadapter, android-view

I have to implement the filters as shown in the image. Which view or component can I use? Popup view or Alert dialog or anything else?
Also, I have implemented my list using an array adapter and I have filter items in that.
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fuWG.jpg

Comment: Using alert dialog you can design your custom alert dialog

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use dialog fragments.
You can read my article on medium on how to create dialog fragment
https://islamassem.medium.com/custom-dialog-using-dialog-fragments-de6a0874b6a4